# Convert Pytorch Yolact (.pth) model for deployment in C++

Tags: python, c++, pytorch, onnx, torchscript

I am using [YOLACT++](https://github.com/dbolya/yolact) and I want to deploy it using C++. Originally the model is saved as yolact.pth file and I realized from the issues that I couldn't directly convert .pth to .pt file that can be called in C++ [see this issue](https://github.com/dbolya/yolact/issues/59) and I would need to do convert it first to ONNX which gives out yolact.onnx as the output. I converted it to ONNX using [this](https://github.com/dbolya/yolact/issues/74#issuecomment-510713725) solution in the issues and in the comments below this one you can see the terminal commands he uses to achieve the yolact.onnx converted model from yolact.pth.

So my issue is I don't really understand what to do next to deploy it using C++. Should I be looking for solutions to convert from yolact.onnx to yolact.pt or can yolact.onnx be called from C++? There's an interesting direction given in one of the issues [here](https://github.com/dbolya/yolact/issues/59#issuecomment-501609792) for this work flow: **Pytorch->ONNX->NCNN** which he tested with C++ inference on ARM device. Is this what I am looking for. I am not very familiar with C++ so I dont know the direction.

I also tried adding this to end of of eval.py where model is being called:

```
    sm = torch.jit.script(net)
    sm.save("Yolact.pt")
```

and I got error:

```
    torch.jit.frontend.UnsupportedNodeError: with statements aren't 
    supported: (line 570 in yolact.py)
```

and line 570 is:

```
     with timer.env('backbone'):
```

I commented it out and it gave error on the next "timer.env" in line 574 and so on!

Comment: Did you try jit tracing it first and see if that works for you?

Comment: @Rika hi im not sure. Can you check my question again I edited it and I put in the thing I added in my code using pytorch tutorials on website

Comment: @Rika I tried tracing again using 
example = torch.rand(1, 3, 550, 550), traced_script_module = torch.jit.trace(net, example)  traced_script_module.save("Yolact.pt")   at the end of eval.py but it gives me errors like RuntimeError: Tracer cannot infer type of [{'detection': {'box': tensor([[-0.4274, -0.5033,  0.4412,  0.4673], and it goes on and on

Comment: and also I dont know what values to put in example=torch.rand(x,x,x,x) my trained images are of size 550x550

Comment: youre doing it correctly but It seems your model doesn't support jit tracing,as indicated in the link you posted. unfortunetaly I'm not familair with your model/onnx.

Comment: Were you actually able to convert one of the Yolact++ models to ONNX?  Such as yolact_plus_base_54_800000.pth to yolact_plus_base_54_800000.onnx.  If when I try with Ma-Dan's solution (as you link above), I get:  'yolact_plus_base_config' is not defined.  My command line is: python3 eval.py --trained_model=yolact_plus_base_54_800000.pth --score_threshold=0.3 --top_k=100 --cuda=False --image=image.jpg

Comment: Did you solve your question?